# How would I convert an integer to a string?

Tags: java, integer

I'm currently typing up a program and was curious as to how I would be able to change an integer input into a letter but it would be the specific amount of times the integer would be.

As an example lets say I asked the user for how many apples they have and they typed in three, how would I then turn that "3" into "aaa", or like if they entered 11 and the output came as "aaaaaaaaaaa". I hope this isn't too bad of an example.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: `yourString.repeat(n);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to program, you'll have to do those yourself;

```
int count = your_number, i = 0;
String letter = your_letter;
String result = "";
while (i < count) {
    result += letter;
    i++;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Or you can use Java Strings.Utils.repeat() function
[Strings.Utils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
String stringToRepeat = "xxx"
int count = your_count;
String repeated = StringUtils.repeat(stringToRepeat, count);
System.out.println(repeated);
```